# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement but I just want to update 1 column

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of file names which I want to insert into my mySQL database. I have done the following:

```
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO table (filename) VALUES(%s)""", folder_files)
```

However, I am getting:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.

The table in the database does have 3 columns but I only want to insert data into the filename column.

My alternative (and working) code is

```
for each_pdf_file in folder_files:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO table (filename) VALUES(%s)", (each_pdf_file,))
    print(each_pdf_file)
```

but this is incredibly slow (I have thousands of files to import into the database).

So how do I use the executemany? Or must I stick to my alternative code?

Comment: How does your `folder_files` list look like?

Comment: I guess `folder_files` is a list, is that it?

Comment: yes `folder_files` is indeed a list. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `folder_files` looks something like this (a list of strings):

```
folder_files = ["folder1", "folder2", "folder3"]
```

But it should actually look like this (a list of one string element tuples):

```
folder_files = [("folder1",), ("folder2",), ("folder3",)]
```

You can easily transform your list to the correct format with a list comprehension:

```
folder_files = [(folder,) for folder in folder_files]
```

---

Here's a relevant section from [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), which hints that you should always have the arguments be in tuples:

> **Note**
>
> In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For example, `('abc')` is evaluated as a scalar while `('abc',)` is evaluated as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have enough format strings to make the sql query.

```
format_string = ('%s, '* len(folder_files))[:-2]
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table (filename) VALUES({})".format(format_string), folder_files)
```